# referencing existing sound objects on the timeline via actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, flash-cs5, timeline

In Actionscript 3 / Flash 10, is it possible to programmatically reference a sound object that exists on the timeline? I've found lots of examples for referencing DisplayObjects via the following sytax:

```
var m:MovieClip = stage.getChildByName("SomeMovieClipClass");
var n:MovieClip = stage.getChildByIndex(1);
```

But this doesn't seem to include sound objects. Similarly, it seems straightforward to instantiate and play a sound that exists in the Library via Actionscript:

```
var s:SoundClip1 = new SoundClip1(); // exported in first frame via properties
s.play();
```

For my purposes, though, I'd like to reference sound clips (ideally in a specific layer, although that seems to be a design-time element) that designers have adjusted and arranged on the timeline, so that I can inspect their waveforms via code, at runtime. Something like this:

```
// Imaginary Code
sc = timeline.getSoundClipByName("SoundClip1");
sc.extract(waveform,sc.length/1000 * bitrate);
```

Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of this date, no it is not possible to access the soundChannel generated by a timeline sound.  It's a feature I would love to see implemented.

I was going to try to test the feasibility of using computeSpectrum to get the waveform of a timeline sound but I'm having problems importing mp3s right now.  In absence of firsthand proof of concept, I searched around and found this thread:

http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?t=329632

Which links to this solution

http://www.mail-archive.com/flashcoders@chattyfig.figleaf.com/msg43157.html

But of course this doesn't allow you to disambiguate between different timeline sounds.  I'm pretty sure you won't be able to do that at all.

I have not ever used Sound.extract(), but if the sounds exist in the fla library this indicates to me that you can simply give them a Class name and at runtime use extract() to gather the waveform for your own purposes, yes?  Then whenever the appropriate timeline sound plays, you can tap into the waveform from the Sound object.  Perhaps a timeline callback or event would suffice for this?

Comment: Surprisingly, giving a sound a Class doesn't seem to result in the constructor being called when the sound starts on the timeline. I don't understand why this is, so as a workaround I'm calling a line of actionscript every time a sound begins on the timeline. It's not pretty, but it's working for the time being.

Comment: Somehow it doesn't surprise me.  I cannot say for certain by I suspect that the sound is constructed when the swf itself it.  The "sounds" you hear are soundChannel objects, and there is no way to extend SoundChannel in any meaningful way (hence, no way to track instantiations).